# Dnsmasq fails to start every time I reboot my VPS

Tags: linux, dns, debian, vps, dnsmasq

Dnsmasq fails to start every time I reboot my VPS. Below is the log about it.

```
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian dnsmasq[776]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian dnsmasq[798]: chown: invalid user: ‘dnsmasq:nogroup’
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 18:14:51 debian systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'd set the user and group name correctly in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file. I tried to reinstall dnsmasq and then it worked. But after I reboot the VPS, it failed to start again. Then I have to reinstall again...

So, If I want to use dnsmasq, I have to not to reboot my VPS. But I want to know what causes this and how to fix it once and for all. My VPS's system is Debian 9, kernel is 4.9.0-7-amd64.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the trouble and fixed it. As the system informed, `chown: invalid user: ‘dnsmasq:nogroup’` is the bad code. I thought it should be dnsmasq failed to automatically add user or group that caused the error.

One solution might be manually adding a user named "dnsmasq". I didn't try it but I thought it would work. Another handling way is to looked up user "dnsmasq" in relative files and replace user "dnsmasq" with an existing user like "nobody".

There are 3 places in the `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` file that need replace.

1. `if [ ! "$DNSMASQ_USER" ]; then
   DNSMASQ_USER="*dnsmasq*"
   fi`
2. `# /run may be volatile, so we need to ensure that
       # /run/dnsmasq exists here as well as in postinst
       if [ ! -d /run/dnsmasq ]; then
          mkdir /run/dnsmasq || return 2
          chown *dnsmasq*:nogroup /run/dnsmasq || return 2
       fi`
3. `# /run may be volatile, so we need to ensure that
       # /run/dnsmasq exists here as well as in postinst
       if [ ! -d /run/dnsmasq ]; then
          mkdir /run/dnsmasq || return 2
          chown *dnsmasq*:nogroup /run/dnsmasq || return 2
       fi`

Replace 3 empasized places above.

Although I'm not sure why dnsmasq failed to access account files.

Comment: Yes, it seems there are many other places that are suitable for some kind of questions. As for deleting, I can not delete the question.

Comment: Update your A to show the 3 places and I will upvote (rather than downvote). Good luck.